# NullReferenceException when using AjaxControlToolKit Gravatar control

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, nullreferenceexception

Whenever I try to add AjaxControlToolKit's Gravatar control in one of my pages the following error comes up:

[image]

I added the library on top of page as

```
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>
```

and control as

```
<asp:Gravatar ID="Gravatar1" runat="server" Height="168px" Width="168px" />
```

And Gravatar control works well in other old ASP.NET pages of my website. But when I try to add it in new pages, it comes up with above exception. Please tell me why the exception is occuring and how can I resolve it? And also why [no relevant source lines] in the Source Error? Please also note that I am unable to drag the gravatar control onto this page from toolbox. I have to write the above code to add the control.

Comment: are you sure it because of ajaxrefrence

Comment: ya I tried removing it and it works fine when there is no Gravatar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `Email` property of the gravatar.

```
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" 
  namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="act" %>

<act:Gravatar ID="Gravatar1" runat="server" Email="someone@somewhere.org" 
  Height="168px" Width="168px" />
```

**Update**

I've just looked at the `Gravatar.GetHash` method.  And its first line is `Email = Email.ToLower();`. This will throw a null exception if the Email is null.

Comment: I am setting the email property at Page_Load(), `Gravatar1.Email = dops.getAuthEmail(up.getUserID());`

Comment: The exception is being thrown from `Gravatar.GetHash(string Email)`.  Are you sure that the email is non-null?

Comment: @ShivaPareek is this code `Gravatar1.Email = dops.getAuthEmail(up.getUserID());` executed only on initial page load (wrapped in `if(!IsPostback)` block)?

Comment: Sorry guys that was my silly mistake. The reason was the same as of @RichardSchneider that Email Property was not set. But I was setting the Email Property but the compiler was unable to reach the assignment code due to exception in calling database function. I forgot to add this code in finally block in my code. Thanks Richard..:)

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing email id as a Session variable use this

> Email='<%=email)%>' where "email" is your session variable .

Other wise you just need to put email id to the Email Property . Thats it !